# BreezeJS expand no more working after upgrade from v1.2 to 1.4?

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

Okay, after much struggle, I just got my project upgraded from Breeze 1.2 to 1.4 and EF 5.0 to 6.1 and it's running. However, I noticed, some of the queries don't work anymore. On client, I got error like this:

> GET
>   .../breeze/breeze/Methods?$filter=Id%20eq%201&$expand=CompoundSettings%2FCompound%2FTargetPeaks
>   400 (Bad Request)

As I read, some people report that breeze doesn't support many-to-many relationship. However, mine is not a many-to-many.

In my case, Methods contains a collection of CompoundSetting, which contains a Compound, which contains a collection of TargetPeak. I also tried to remove virtual keyword for collection, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

If the expand doesn't include the last TargetPeaks, it works.

What's the problem? Too many nested layers? Please note the same query (with even more layers) worked fine in Breeze v1.2.

Comment: I have the same versions: Breeze:1.4 and EF: 6.1 . Would you post the client code with the expand?

Comment: In the meantime, I moved those expands to server using include which doesn't have any problem. My project is working again. The client code I used to use looks like this: `var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Methods').expand('CompoundSettings.Compound.TargetPeaks');
return manager.executeQuery(query).then(succeeded);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be having the problem described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668693/maxexpansiondepth-with-latest-webapi-and-breeze).

Older versions of EF and WebApi did not support $expand, so the Breeze EF server code used its own implementation for $expand.  Now, with WebApi 2, Breeze uses Microsoft's implementation, which uses Microsoft's defaults.

The `Queryable` attribute includes a "MaxExpansionDepth" property, to prevent clients from being able to make too large a query.  I'm not sure what the default is, but try:

```
[BreezeQueryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 4)]
public IQueryable<Method> Methods()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's the secret sauce. And the Breeze upgrade didn't do this to you. The Web API 2 upgrade did.

Comment: Great. I just tested with this and it works. As mentioned in the other post, you can add this attribute either to method level or controller level. Too bad for me, because in the meantime, I converted all expands to server side includes which works well. But good to know the solution for this problem and I'm sure I'll need it  later. Thanks a million!